# Can i keep my token inside my private network forever?

Tags: tokens, private-blockchain, testnets

I have created a token in ropsten test network, can i keep it in same network forever or create a new private network and keep it there without moving to main network? What are the merits and demerits?

Answer (score 1):

You can't move tokens around between networks. It belongs to one network and it's only accessible within that network.

The same goes for Ether: if you mine some Ether in your private network you can't transfer it to the mainnet for huge profits.

Comment: My question is, do i need to deploy my token contract in mainnet again? Is there any merits in having a token in mainnet vs private net? Can a token in private net be launched for ICOs or be exchanged for ethers or dollars?

Comment: No, the networks do not have any bridges between them. In theory you may get someone to give you mainnet Ether for private network tokens, but that's quite unlikely unless it's a big and successful private net token. So, yes, if you want to have generally accepted token, you need to deploy to the mainnet. Private nets are good for prototyping and different tests.

Comment: So in private network, i cannot buy real ethers? I am not talking about the test networks like infura. I am talking about the private network which can be participated within my organization?

Comment: No, the private network is....private. Real Ether is only available in the mainnet. You can have Ether in your own network also, but that's not interchangeable with real Ether - it's your own network's Ether.

Comment: how can we buy own own network ether? should i pay for that?